# Jquery resize calculation glitch

Tags: jquery, width, window-resize

I have set a jQuery width calculation for resizing my window and it all works fine but I find that when I resize and stretch, there is a 'glitch' or split seconds where the widths of the containers vary, they overlap and leave wide gaps. I understand this is because jQuery is performing it's calculations but is this normal and is there anyway around it?

```
if ($("#Grid").css("margin-bottom") === "1px") {
    oneCol();
}

if ($("#Grid").css("margin-bottom") === "0px") {
    twoCol();
}

function oneCol () {
    $('#middle').hide();
    $('#Grid').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=170px');
}

function twoCol() {
    $('#middle').show();

    $('#middle').outerWidth(function () {
        return ($(this).parent().width() * 0.5) - $('#left').outerWidth() / 2;
    });

    $('#Grid').outerWidth(function () {
        return ($(this).parent().width() * 0.5) - $('#left').outerWidth() / 2;
    });
}


$(window).on('resize', function () {
    if ($("#Grid").css("margin-bottom") === "1px") {
        oneCol();
    }

    if ($("#Grid").css("margin-bottom") === "0px") {
        twoCol();
    }
});
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Alga/9LGA9/12/).

Comment: I don't see a glitch on resizing: is this browser specific?  If so, what browser does this appear on?

Comment: I'm looking at it on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I see the glitch a bit more on Chrome.  Not sure if you can totally eliminate it, but it looks a lot better by optimizing the resizing routines:

```
function oneCol () {
    $('#middle').hide();
    $('#Grid').width( $(window).width() - $('#left').outerWidth() );
}

function twoCol() {
    $('#middle').show();
    var w = ($(window).width() - $('#left').outerWidth())/2;
    $('#middle').width(w);
    $('#Grid').width(w);
 }


$(window).on('resize', function () {
    if ($(window).width()<100) {
        oneCol();
    } else {
        twoCol();
    }
});
```

You can add padding and border in the jQuery too, if you need outerWidth.

(I also eliminated the @media rule from the css--not sure if this makes much difference: if so, you can add box-sizing, etc. in with jQuery as well).